# Running out of memory during CSV file creation

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a report that I have to write code to run, it has to compile a month's worth of data into a CSV file. The data is something close to 112,000 lines long and 47 cells of data per line.

I'm running out of memory as I try to write the file. I thought something with `fflush` might do it but it doesn't seem to. The code is in PHP.

```
$filename = str_replace(array('-',':','_', ' '), '', "export_" . date("m-d-Y H:i:s") . ".csv");
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","changedForSecurity","reports");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM testing");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    if ($i < 15000) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
        $i++;
    } else {
        fflush($fp);
        $i=1;
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

}
```

Comment: upgrade your memory limit in your php.ini

Comment: I don't see how this script could be running out of memory. It never has more than one row from the database in memory. You don't need to call `fflush()`, PHP will flush the buffer automatically whenever it fills up. Some other part of the script must be causing the problem, not the section you've posted.

Comment: After it writes the file, is there another part of the script that downloads it? I suspect the memory problem is there.

Comment: Ill put this as a comment as it does not answer your question, but if you have access to the database file system have you considered getting mysql to handle the csv creation : SELECT query_here
FROM table_here
INTO OUTFILE 'myfile.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your memory limit setting.  This can be done either by manually changing it in the `php.ini` file or you can do it in the code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Or in the `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

One thing to note is that you should try to limit the amount you set here.  If yours is set to `64M` then try `128M` first.  Or if it's set to `128M` then try `256M`.  It's overkill to set it too high if it's not necessary.

You can check how much memory you're using by doing this:

```
$initMemory = memory_get_usage();
// your code
$afterMemory = memory_get_usage() - $initMemory;
echo $afterMemory;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from increasing your memory limit in the ini you could also just split the file.  Not nearly as elegant, but it works in a pinch.